# Java Reopen ServerSocket for new connections

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, loops

I have the following code for a java echo server that listens for an incoming request and replies the sent text.

```
public class EchoServer {
    int port;
    ServerSocket server;
    Socket client;
    BufferedWriter bw;
    BufferedReader br;

    EchoServer() throws IOException{
        int port = 1234;
        while(true){
            server = new ServerSocket(port);
            client = server.accept();
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

            bw.write(br.readLine());
            bw.newLine();
            bw.flush();

            bw.close();
            br.close();
            client.close();
            server.close();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
        new EchoServer();
    }
}
```

But I think that is ineffecient because every object gets recreated in the loop. If I would modify the loop to the following

```
while(true){
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
        client = server.accept();
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));

        bw.write(br.readLine());
        bw.newLine();
        bw.flush();
}

bw.close();
br.close();
client.close();
server.close();
```

I can handle many requests, but only from on client.
What can I do to get the following behaviour:

- Handle an infinite amount of request
- Handle every request sequentially,only one request at a time
- No unnecessary creating of objects or closing of streams/sockets
- without Threads

Is it even possible to implement this behaviour without Threads, because I don't want things to get unnecessarily complicated. If it's not possible, how could I implement this with the use of Threads?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your objectives are in conflict unless you move to non-blocking NIO. To fix this present code, you need to:

1. Move the `new ServerSocket(port)` line before the `while` loop, and move the close to after it.
2. Start a new thread per accepted socket, to handle its I/O.

This is how most Java servers work.

Comment: OP doesn't seem to require concurrent processing of requests.  See second bullet point.  His question seems to be about the lack of concurrent connection establishment product of closing the `ServerSocket` continuously or at least after every connection.

Comment: @MarioRossi OP requires "infinite amount of request" and "handle every request sequentially,only one request at a time". That includes multiple requests from a single client. It isn't possible without multiplexed I/O or threads in blocking mode.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of a `ServerSocket` is that you **do not** have to create it every time.  Take creation (and closing) out of the loop.  Among other things, this will cause that clients sending connect requests at the same time are queued and served on the next call to `server.accept()`.  If you close the `ServerSocket` on each loop, the queue of pending clients is lost.

On an aside, if you are so adverse to creating objects maybe you should not be using Java or any other OOPL, as their APIs are constantly creating and destroying objects.  What do you think happens in many of them when you concatenate two Strings?  And what makes you believe that object creation is so terribly inefficient?  If you develop programs in an OOPL with these ideas in mind, you will make them very difficult to maintain, fragile, and probably less efficient in the long run.

Comment: I think there is a missunderstanding, i don't have a problem with crearting and destroying objects, but with doing that when not needed, in my code the serversocket does not need to be recreated every time the loop is run

Comment: @danielr1996 If you know it isn't necessary, why are you doing it?

Comment: I didn't know it when i posted the answer, but because oft the answers I know it now